# When is $x^3+x+n$ reducible?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I am trying to work out when $f=x^3+x+n$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. So far, I have reduced to irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}$ by Gauss's lemma, and have that $f=(x+a)(x^2-ax+c)$. It is also clear that $f$ is reducible for $n=0,2,-2$. How should I proceed?

Comment: A monic polynomial $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $2$ or $3$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ iff its has an integer root.  If $f(k)=0$ for some integer $k$, then what can you say about $n$?

Comment: Let $k$ be an arbitrary natural number and let $n=-k^3-k$. Then $k$ is a root of $x^3+x+n$ and therefore there are infinitely many $n$'s for which $f(x)$ is reducible.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A034262

Answer (score 1):

Let ${p\over q}$,  $q>1$ a solution such that $gcd(p,q)=1$, we have ${p^3\over q^3}+{p\over q}+n=0$ implies that $p^3+q^2p+nq^3=0$ implies that $p^3=-q^2(p+nq)$ we deduce that $q$ divides $p$ contradiction.

We can suppose that $q=1$, we have $p^3+p+n=0$ implies that $p(p^2+1)=-n$, the polynomial is reducible if and only if $n=-p(p^2+1)$ where $p$ is an integer. Example, $p=2, n=-2(4+1)=-10$, we have $2^3+2-10=0$